# Shady Business plot: choices, consequences and rewards

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

During the Shady Business plot, I need to choose which corporation to seek funding from for Ho t`Sht's (Inspired name as always) matter/antimatter thingamajig project. Ho t'Sht isn't being particularly informative about the consequences of this decision. What happens if I choose to use one of the three corporations? Do I get different rewards? Are any of these rewards unobtainable by other means? Will the other corporations take it personally? Will there be any other meaningful choices down the road?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing side make some of future missions easier, and 2 other sites will attack your property in future.
Every side have different reward:

- Strong Arms

  1. 5 000 000 credits
  2. Split Heavy Dragon for next mission
  3. Pteranodon (M2) blueprint
- Jonferco

  1. 15 000 000 credits
  2. peaceful solution for one of next missions
  3. Lotan (TS+) blueprint
- Beryll arm of the Yaki Syndicate

  1. resources for one of next missions
  2. Adanced Chokaro (TM) blueprint
  3. Pirate stations available at Yaki Shipyard.

One of missions requires 10 spaceflies. If you have troubles collecting them, then choose Yaki side (Berill will give you 10 spaceflies and other materials needed for mission).

The only unique reward is the access to IBL and PBG factories at the Yaki shipyard you get for choosing Beryll. You can also get the unique Advanced Chokaro blueprints for siding with Beryll (regardless of your choice re: Goner Ozias) or get the ship itself (can be reverse-engineered) for giving a copy of the Xenon legacy code to Beryll if you did not side with them.

Your property will be attacked after you obtain modified ship. After that in 6-12 hour in-game time you will advance to next part of plot (attacks will stop). During this time 2 other factions would independently try to kill you or your property every 50-70 minutes. Your Headquarters can be attacked but will be invincible during attack.

Attackers will be spawned as members of a generic hostile faction, killing them will not lower your reputation with any race.

Sources:

- http://roguey.co.uk/x3ap/help/guides/shady-business/page5.php
- http://x3tc.ru/gryaznye-delishki-ap-3-0_175.html

Comment: Are any of these rewards unique? Do I need to sabotage peace talks to get Beryll's Advanced Chokaro? What makes it easier to get spaceflies if I choose Beryll? Will attacks on my property stop at some point? Do I lose reputation for destroying those attackers?

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: pirate stations at the yaki shipyard is pretty awesome.

Comment: @spartacus yeah, I bought 50 PBG and IBL forges for when I inevitably piss them off again. Any idea if killing the hit squads the 2 scorned corps send after you affect your reputation? I'd hate to stop being BFFs with 2 main races.

Comment: pffft, if you haven't pissed off at least 2 races in X you aren't doing it right.  You have to have someone to provide you with an endless suppily of M1 and M2s for credits :P

Comment: If they after you, jump to war sectors, may be terran kill them, ot make unfocused jump, they may dissapear on way back.